Efficiently updating RecyclerView items based on unchanged SharedPreferences keys
Question: I have an Android app where I store data using SharedPreferences, and I have a RecyclerView displaying items based on keys from SharedPreferences. The keys remain constant, but the data associated with each key can change. What is the best approach to efficiently update specific RecyclerView items when the data changes without altering the keys themselves? Should I use notifyItemChanged even if the keys remain the same? Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated.
I wish to know how notifyitemchanged behave, does it follow the change in array or not

Just show your code. Show how you do it now. After that maybe someone suggests something.

When 1 item in the data set changes you would use notifyItemChanged which causes that item to be updated in the recyclerview

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
